# Is it possible to make an monitor that can output colors perfectly?

Tags: color, color-spaces, display-calibration, monitors, human-vision-system

We have come from long way from my rather bad IBM E74 monitor with terrible color reproduction to the brand new monitors with 14 Bit HDR.

But will we ever see an monitor that can output colors that will be so accurate our eyes won't be able to see the difference from it to the image it sees looking out from the Window?

In other words. Will there be an CIELAB monitor? I know its rather stupid to support an color space that has imaginary colors but will we ever see hundred percent real color monitors? Three diode LED's exist after all so I think its theoritically possible to find gasses that can output any color or rather colors we can see.

Comment: Define Perfect ?? Is the red you see perfect or is the red  i see perfect? Whose eyes/brain will be the standard?

Comment: @AlaskaMan we can make a basis or some random person or make service s enters where we can acan our eyes and plug the eye data in our computers.

Comment: I couldn't resist the temptation to answer, but I probably should have. I think this is off topic for this site, as it doesn't really have any application in even the theory of photography today, and it's also asking us to speculate on the future.

Comment: Far more goes into the image you see looking out the window than just color - binocular vision (i.e. having two eyes) gives parallax and depth perception. There's motion and changing light and shadows. Monitors have a long way to go, not just in color reproduction, before that ideal is reached...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the site guidelines specifically exclude speculation about future technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, sure — all you need to do is make primaries that exactly match the S, M, and L cone types in the human eye. Not just in peak, but with the exact same response curve. You might not be able to do this properly with a monitor per se — you may need to beam it directly into the eyes with high precision. (If we can solve the other part, this should be a piece of cake.)

Now, I can't imagine how that would be done with current technology and materials. But in theory, sure, why not. Probably around the same time we have cold fusion and room-temperature superconductors.

That said, there's probably no necessity. The human vision system is remarkably adaptive — that's why we have to *learn* the idea of color temperature, and why many people don't notice anything wrong with spectrum-deficient fluorescent lights. We just need to get close enough and the brain will fill in the rest.

Comment: Another possibility in sci-fi land would be to map the individual retina and pinpoint each cell directly. However, this pretty far off of any practical application to photography as we know it.

Comment: Or switch from a three-color model to some fantasy laser with infinitely variable frequency response.

Comment: retro futuristic CRT that uses an laser that shoots to an screen that uses some futuristic particles or simply directly to the eye. Now that's a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible - If we could, you would need to don sunglasses to view sunny beach vista. Plus, objects in the real world have texture, we can't duplicate such a surface on a screen. We can't duplicate the colors exactly.

Comment: I don't think texture has some ting to do with it. It's after all what the sensor sees in the end.

Comment: It also would look epic. Explosions frying your eyes in a movie. I guess we could make an algorithm that would tone down the brightness and sell it to the film makes tho

Comment: @ DOU - Real objects have texture. To replicate, the image must produce the illusion that the display also has texture. A typical sunlit vista has a brightness range that far exceeds what we can display on a computer or movie screen. In fact our displays pales in comparison to the real world.